# why does this AWS Lambda code in Java return "internal server error" when invoked via an API gateway?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

From my understanding, if you return the following json string: `{"headers":{"Content-Type":"application/json"},"body":"hello world","statusCode":200}`

then when visiting the page https://....eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/, you should see the phrase "hello world" written. Instead, I get `{"message": "Internal server error"}`

Below is the JAVA code I am using to return the above json string:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import java.util.Map;

public class Handler implements RequestHandler<Map<String, String>, JSONObject>{
    @Override
    public JSONObject handleRequest(Map<String, String> stringStringMap, Context context) {

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject();
        obj2.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
        obj.put("statusCode", 200);
        obj.put("headers", obj2);
        obj.put("body", "hello world");
        return obj;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? It works fine on the console when I test the function, but when I go to the page of the API it gives me an internal server error.

Comment: Have you checked CloudWatch Logs for the lambda? Maybe it errors out?

Comment: @kmpt You should review the API logs. They'll show what causes the Server Error.

Comment: you are correct, I get 'java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred during JSON parsing Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: com.amazonaws.lambda.thirdparty.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token'

Comment: That sounds like it wants a String containing the JSON, not a JSONObject.

Answer (score 2):

The error message you posted in the comment has already explained what the problem is. Basically, lambda handler is not able to convert the input object to `String`. You can solve this by changing `Map<String, String>` to `Map<String, Object>` or general `Object`.

Also, as @david pointed out in the comment, you should return a JSON String instead of a `JSONObject`. So the fully working code could be something like this:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import java.util.Map;

public class Handler implements RequestHandler<Map<String, Object>, String>{
    @Override
    public String handleRequest(Map<String, Object> stringStringMap, Context context) {

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject();
        obj2.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
        obj.put("statusCode", 200);
        obj.put("headers", obj2);
        obj.put("body", "hello world");
        return obj.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: it seems to be executing fine now without any errors in the logs, but I still get the same message when I visit the website... I get the following in the logs every time I visit the website: 'REPORT RequestId: d28cc5cc-6af8-4045-adf7-0836620d46b3 Duration: 1.80 ms Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 89 MB'

but the message written in the body is the same. I will check it again tomorrow (maybe it takes time for the website to update?)

Comment: unfortunately I was still getting the same error when I woke up... can it be something related to Strings? I really want to understand why for example using streams (see my answer) worked but not Strings...

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, the following code worked fine for me:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestStreamHandler;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

import java.io.*;

public class Handler implements RequestStreamHandler{
    @Override
    public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, 
                                      Context context) throws IOException {

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject();
        obj2.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
        obj.put("statusCode", 200);
        obj.put("headers", obj2);
        obj.put("body", "hello world");

        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8");
        writer.write(obj.toString());
        writer.close();

    }

}
```